# Combine two scopes in Rails 4 in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please note that similar questions are concerning Rails 3, and the scopes having changed a moderate amount in Rails 4. Only syntactically, but I still would like to have an up-to-date answer.

Anyway, how do I merge these scopes:

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :recent, -> { order('cats.approve_date ASC').limit(5) }
    scope :approved, -> { where( state: 'approved') }
end
```

If I want to get all the recent cats:

```
@recent_cats = Cat.recent
```

If I want to get all the approved cats:

```
@approved_cats = Cat.approved
```

But how do I get all the recent and approved cats? I could use the `merge` function in the controller, but I want to follow conventions and do this in the model:

```
class Cat < AciveRecord::Base
    scope :recent_approved, -> { }
end
```

Comment: Cat.approved.recent will work.

Comment: @Iceman While I did say I wanted to do this in the model, that's a pretty readable way to do it..thanks!

Comment: You can eventually put `self.recent.approved` in the `:recent_approved` scope

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks, thought it was simple. Accepted answer right there if you want it :)

Comment: The credit goes to @Iceman, he should post an answer.

Comment: Can I suggest comething? `scope :recent, ->(nb_limit = 5) { order('cats.approve_date ASC').limit(nb_limit) }` So it would let you choose how many you want, default is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain scopes like this.

```
@cats = Cat.approved.recent
```

But using scopes is also possible

```
scope :recent_approved, -> { where(state: 'approved').order(:approve_date).limit(5) }
```